# Caret is not coming between spans (contenteditable="false") on div (contenteditable="true")

Tags: javascript, html, css

My caret is not coming between spans, below example

> **REPLY||stick together||CONFIRM||stick together||Name||stick together||Office**

All my spans are stick together and all spans are `contenteditable="false"` and my main div is `contenteditable="true"`.

Problem -> caret is not coming between these spans, it goes before all spans or after all spans.

```html
<div id="variable-message-input-message" class="variable-message__compose" contenteditable="true" name="message">
  Hi
  <span spellcheck="false" contenteditable="false" draggable="true" id="span-First Name" class="variable-message__variable">
       Name
       </span> , This is just a friendly reminder for your upco
  <span spellcheck="false" contenteditable="false" draggable="true" id="span-REPLY ‘2’ to CANCEL" class="variable-message__variable">
       REPLY
       </span>
  <span spellcheck="false" contenteditable="false" draggable="true" id="span-REPLY ‘1’ to CONFIRM" class="variable-message__variable">
       CONFIRM
       </span>
  <span spellcheck="false" contenteditable="false" draggable="true" id="span-Last Name" class="variable-message__variable">
       Name
       </span>
  <span spellcheck="false" contenteditable="false" draggable="true" id="span-Office Location" class="variable-message__variable">
       Office
       </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The spans aren't editable, why should the caret appear on them?

Comment: Not exactly related, but the `id`s are invalid, they should not contain white-space characters.

Comment: I want my caret can move on sides of span, not to appear on them. caret should be behave one letter as one word and move left or right. but my caret just stucks. not able to move that part. @Barmar

Comment: It works for me in Chrome.

Comment: @Barmar you can run code as snipet here, after REPLY i can't move caret forward and if i go at last, then i can move caret in left, it stucks.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I put the cursor on `upco`, then used the right-arrow. It went to `REPLY`, then skipped past it, then skipped past `CONFIRM`.

Comment: But it doesn't work in Safari.

Comment: Works a bit odd with Firefox,at first just like Barmar described, but when coming back with arrow keys, it jumps over all the spans back to "upco", and the span gaps can't be focused by clicking at all. Contentediable elements are not good with this, maybe you should use spans and text inputs instead?

Comment: It works in Firefox.

Comment: Yeah, it mostly works in FF, but not as nicely as Chrome.

Comment: My guess is that this isn't well specified in HTML, and the browser designers have interpreted it differently.

Comment: @Barmar I don't how it working on your side but it stucks here, Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant yeah i feel the same in chrome. it skip Name ( 2nd letter ) span. But it is not skipping when i put together all the spans. Like in example REPLY Confirm part. It stucks when my caret comes on REPLY part

Comment: I'm in 77.0.3865.120, and now it's updating again.

Comment: Well, like stated, contenteditables are not consistent across browsers, and the markup they produce is awful in all browsers.

Comment: span are inline, make them a real box via inline-block, then it works as expected or at least the same everywhere i guess :(

Comment: @Barmar it works well when i updated to chrome version to `v77`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It was the version specific issue, as my chrome version was **v75** and when i update to **v77** latest. My above snippet works well.

Comment: But not in Safari 13 or latest Firefox.